# How rand variables work?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm running a sample test for Systemverilog on rand variables.
Why isn't a1 being randomized in this module?

```
class  Simple;
    rand bit [1:0] a1;
    randc bit [1:0] b1;
endclass

Simple p = new;

initial begin
   $display("Randomize state %d",p.a1.rand_mode());
   for (int i=0;i<=3;i++) begin
        p.randomize();
        $display("\a1 is %d",p.a1);
        $display("\b1 is %d",p.b1);
   end
end
```

Result:

```
 Randomize state           1
    a1 is 3
    b1 is 2
    a1 is 3
    b1 is 3
    a1 is 3
    b1 is 0
    a1 is 3
    b1 is 1
```

Comment: Works for me (after wrapping your code in a module and removing the \ )
`# run -all
# Randomize state           1
# a1 is 0
# b1 is 3
# a1 is 1
# b1 is 0
# a1 is 0
# b1 is 2
# a1 is 2
# b1 is 1`

Comment: When inserting the new statement in the initial block, I get 2 0 2 2 as a1's random sequence. This might be a tool-specific thing. What tool are you using?

Comment: I use Questa. Try running a loop of 10.

Comment: yes that did it. I newed the rand variable outside the initial block and upped the iteration to 10. a1 is now `3 3 3 3 0 3 2 1 3 3`.
the odds of getting a1 to randomize to 3 four times in a row is 1/64.  I guess that's the difference between rand and randc. With randc, we're guaranteed to cycle through the range. With rand, we're not. 
I'm not sure why this post is getting voted down. It was a legitimate question. Thank you Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rand modifier randomizes an integral variable to a uniform distribution with its range. There is a 1/range chance of it picking a value within that range.

In this case the range of a1 is 4 and the simulator randomly picked 3 for the first four iterations of the for loop. There is a 1/64 chance of this happening.

The rand modifier works as expected.